# How to read IL in C++

Tags: c#, c++, mono, il

I would like to know how it is possible to read IL from a managed library or executable, and parse the metadata in the file, similar to how Mono.Cecil works. The reason I am doing this is to port some .NET code to Android (and a few other platforms), without having to pay the outrageous fee for Mono. I am wondering if the IL code used in these files is documented somewhere. Mono's parser seems to be very messy. I'd like to read the actual specification, instead of a C# implementation of it.

Comment: Did you google for the specification? http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm (Partition II and III are probably what you want)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of IL decompilers and tools out there; it should be relatively easy to read whatever instructions or metadata you want, and do with them whatever you want.

... BUT ...

Most of these .Net tools are themselves written in .Net.  Which is fine, if you're willing to whatever you need on a Windows workstation (then copy the final output to your target device).

As far as finding a decompiler library or tool that actually RUNS on your Android target ... that's a bit more problematic :)

Anyway, have a look here:

http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx

Good luck!

Comment: I'll probably end up using either this or raw cecil, and writing my own assembly language that it will compile the IL to. I'll be sure to open-source it too on my GitHub page: https://github.com/IDWMaster. It is probably best to compile to another assembly language (or machine code), then deploy to the device.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you need to decompile anything, don't you have the source code to your own assemblies? You don't need to decompile those in order to port them to c++.

If you are trying to decompile .NET assemblies that you do not own, then that sounds like copyright theft.

Also, Mono is Free Software. If you are writing Free Software (i.e. comply with the terms of the LGPL license), you can use vanilla Mono on Android and don't need a commercial Mono4Android license.

In other words: You only have to pay if you do not comply with the terms of the Free Software licenses (which is pretty fair if you ask me).

Comment: The reason I'm disassembling them is so I can make my own "deploy" engine built into Visual Studio (compile the binaries, disassemble them, convert the assembly to my own binary format, then deploy). Also; in terms of the license, I was under the impression that if it was an "embedded" device, even if it was an open-source project, I would have to pay for it.

Comment: Ah, now I see what you are doing... something sorta like the dalvik compiler.